# How to import .dng files

Tags: import

I have to work with `.dng` files and it looks like you can do it in Blender, somehow.

As stated in [this question](https://developer.blender.org/T33003), it seems that you can import them but I don't know how; how do I do this?

Comment: I tried to do as is stated here - http://www.blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?292815-Can-t-open-DNG-files, so I downloaded that `test.dng` from question you linked, opened it with Photoshop, and was able then to save it as TIFF or JPEG (or PSD, then having even more formats to select from).

Comment: Ok, but I need to work in float point and preferably without using any proprietary software. Anyway, this question is about importing in Blender and it seems that it worked in that link.

Comment: You could convert the files to exrs using [natron](https://natron.inria.fr/) or [after effects](http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/13456/is-there-a-way-to-directly-save-dng-sequences-to-16bit-exr-sequences-in-photosho)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It did not work in the link you provided. The bug was that the DNG actually crashed blender. The bug causing the crash was resolved, but DNG was still not supported.

There is a discussion here: http://www.magiclantern.fm/forum/index.php?topic=6457.0  about converting DNG to EXR which may be of interest to you.